# Bash - get all the children of a process even the ended ones

Tags: bash

In a Bash script I have a process A that runs a process B that ends very quickly and that, in turns, runs itself other processes. I would like to get all the descendants of A, but it's like if A did not have any children. I tried to use:

```
pgrep -P <A's PID>
```

and

```
ps -o pid= --ppid <A's PID>
```

but I get no children.

How could I get all the children of A, even the ended ones, and all it's descendants?

Comment: Unless A itself is recording the processes it spawns somewhere, the OS doesn't keep a record of former processes.

Comment: If there's an option to log all processes (for auditing purposes, for example) in your operating system, what it is and how to use it is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please explain why you need this feature. As above, most OS's don't have this feature. If you ***really*** need this information, the easiest and most stable solution would be to add code that at the top of each process logs what ever data you need into a file. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

This short Bash program illustrates one possible way of doing what you want:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

set -o monitor

((sleep 3 & sleep 4 &); sleep 5) &
pgid=$!

sleep 1     # Allow time for all descendant processes to start

pgrep -g "$pgid" -a

wait
```

- `set -o monitor` turns on [job control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_(Unix)) for the program.  Job control is not enabled by default for non-interactive shells.  One effect of enabling job control is that all background processes get their own [process groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group).  A child background process and all if its descendants all become members of the same process group.
- `((sleep 3 & sleep 4 &); sleep 5) &` starts a background process.  That process creates a child process that runs `sleep 3` and `sleep 4` in the background and exits.  That means that `sleep 3` and `sleep 4` become [orphan processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process).  However, they retain the same process group id as the top-level background process.
- `pgid=$!` stores the PID of the top-level background process.  It is also the process group ID for the new process group.
- `pgrep -g "$pgid" -a` lists details of the processes in the process group of the top-level background process.  In this case it lists `.../bash ...` (the shell created by the outermost `(...)`), `sleep 3`, `sleep 4`, and `sleep 5`.
- The child process created by the inner `(...)` has exited and been waited for by its parent shell, so there is no record of it left (unless maybe some form of process auditing is active).  It does not appear in the `pgrep` output.